# JS Regular Expression - global number of char

Tags: javascript, regex

I would a regular expression to determinate a string that allows:
-at least 2 digit;
-at least 1 capital letter
-at least one of this char: !,$,?

My principal problem is that those chars can be situated in any position!

Ex:
**1dfA2!** it's ok like **11Aw!**

Practically, the occurrence has to be global.

EDIT: i tried, step by step, first only with number, but my problem is with the position!

```
/(0-9){2}/g
```

i'm at the start with regex

Comment: Wheres your attempt at solving this?

Comment: My attempt was ridiculous, because i'm poor in theory. I think that it wouldn't help the discussion. In any case i tried, step by step first with only the numbers in any position. Obviously was wrong. I think that in some case, if the code is so poor, it is only a bad extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following lookahead assertion:

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!$?]).*$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/9)

Comment: Thank you! It's wonderful! Studying your answer i've understood many things!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike karthik's solution, this one will find all on the same line:

```
/(?:\s|^)(?=(?:[^\s]*?\d){2,})(?=[^\s]*?[A-Z])(?=[^\s]*?[!$?])(.*?)(?=\s|\n|$)/gm
```

The matches will be contained in group 1.

This assumes that you are the things you are interested in are separated by spaces.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/tT4cW0/5).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case it's not necessary more one line. But it's useful for my study!